# SUM in excel, which the cells are specified by other cell with formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need your help, I have in two cells `(AA4,AA5)` formulas that calculate which is the 1st date of the current month and which is the last day (column R) and are getting the cell which is the amount of the specific date (column T).

This is a dynamic formula (Every month the cells change).

I need to do a sum of the cells that are returned by the formula.

For current month are $T$31 and $T$61.

I have tried to do the following:

```
=SUM(AA4:AA5) <- returns 0

=SUM(CELL("address";INDEX(T1:T60000;MATCH(EOMONTH(TODAY();-1)+1;R1:R60000;0)));(CELL("address";INDEX(T1:T60000;MATCH(EOMONTH(TODAY();0);R1:R60000;1))))) <- returns #VALUE!
```

If somebody has an idea please share it!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: SUMIF or SUMIFS is your formula, you can sum cells given one condition (SUMIF) or given many conditions (SUMIFS)

Comment: @Wolf - it is usually better to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52765916/edit) instead of adding information in comments

Comment: @Damian I couldn't manage to use SUMIF, can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMIFS with the dates bracketed

```
=SUMIFS(T:T,R:R,">=" & EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,R:R,"<=" & EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))
```

Comment: Looks like OP has semicolons instead of commas, but spot on otherwise.

Comment: I replaced them and it works like a charm. Thank you Scott. Much appreciated.